# $[0,1]$ quotient space of $]0,1[$, but not the other way around.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I want to show that $[0,1]$ is a quotient space of $]0,1[$, but not the other way around. I found so far that $]0,1[$ is no quotient space of $[0,1]$.

Assume it was, then there would be a surjective function $f: [0,1] \longrightarrow]0,1[$, such that $\forall A \subset \, ]0,1[: A \, is \, open \, in \, ]0,1[ \Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(A) \, is \, open \, in \, [0,1]$. Then $f$ is continuous and since $[0,1]$ is compact, $f([0,1])$ is compact too, so $]0,1[$ is compact, which is wrong. Hence there is no such function, therefore $]0,1[$ is not a quotient space of $[0,1]$.

Now to show that $[0,1]$ is a quotient space of $]0,1[$, I tried this. Let be:

$$f:\,]0,1[ \longrightarrow [0,1]: \, x \longmapsto \lvert cos(\frac{1}{x}) \rvert $$

Then f is surjective. Then all I need to show is that $\forall A \subset \, [0,1]: A \,is\,open \Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(A) \,is\,open$.

One way is obvious. Since $f$ is continuous, if $A$ is open $\Longrightarrow$ $f^{-1}(A)$ is open.

Now I need to show that if for some $A \subset \, [0,1]$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is open, then $A$ is open too. Any hints? Or is there maybe another function that makes this way easier. Or should I try a different approach?

Answer (score 5):

For the quotient map, you can try the much simpler (geometrically) map $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\leq \frac{1}{3}\\3x-1&\frac13<x<\frac 23\\1&x\geq \frac 23\end{cases}$$

This makes describing $f^{-1}(A)$ much easier.

Comment: $f$ is continuous, so if $A$ is open, $f{-1}(A)$ is open. So what remains is that if $f^{-1}(A)$ is open, then $A$ is open. f^{-1}(A) can be written as the union of open intervals in $]0,1[$. So if it was true for any interval $I$ that $f(I)$ was open too, then it would be true for $f(f^{-1}(A)) = A$, right?.

Comment: If $f^{-1}(A)$ is open, then $f^{-1}(A)\cap(1/3,2/3)$ is open in $[0,1]$ (why?) Then you have to consider the cases where one or both of $0,1\in A$.

Comment: $f^{-1}(A) \cap (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3})$ is open in $(0,1)$, and therefore also in $[0,1]$. One could show it by saying it's the intersection between $\mathbb{R}$ and an open set in it and so on, but I think it's trivial enough to say it. Now let's say $0 \in A$. If $A = \{0\}$, then $f^{-1}(A) = (0,\frac{1}{3}]$, which isn't open anymore. So if $0$ is in $A$, it has to be included in an open set in $A$. But I don't see how to write this. Isn't there a less tedious way?

Comment: Different question: Can I assume $f^{1}(A)$ is an open interval and prove it for an interval. Then say that in general $f^{-1}(A)$ is the union of open intervals, which will then lead me to the same result?

Comment: Not in general you couldn't (imagine if you tried that with your original function, where $f^{-1}(A)$ is an interval only when $A=[0,1]$.) There are reasons you might be able to do that with this $f$, but it would require an argument. @J.C.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Assume I had proven it if $f^{-1}(A)$ is an open interval. Then if $f^{1}(A)$ is any open set, then I can write it as disjoint union of intervals in $(0,1)$. If $0 \in A$, then one of those intervals will be of the form $(0,b)$ with $b \in (\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]$ and similar if $1 \in A$, and if both are in $A$. So if $f^{-1}(A) = \bigcup I_i$ for some disjoint open intervals $I_i$ that map into disjoint open sets in $[0,1]$, then their union will too, since by construction, $f(\bigcup I_i) = \bigcup f(I_i)$. So $A = f(f^{-1}(A))$ is open. Is that right?

Comment: Any open set in $(0,1)$ is the union of disjoint open intervals. Show that each of these intervals is also of the form $f^{-1}(B)$ for some interval $B$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: If you find a suitable $f$ that is an open mapping (as J.C. did originally), then you don't have to agonise about what sets of the form $f^{-1}(A)$ look like. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a slightly less wiggly example for the quotient mapping is
$$
f(x) = \frac{1 + \sin(2\pi x)}{2}
$$
But the proof is much the same for either your example or the above: show that for each $x \in ]), 1[$, and for all sufficiently small $\delta$, $f(]x - \delta, x + \delta[)$ is an open subset of $[0, 1]$ of one of the three forms 
$$[0, \epsilon[\\
]y - \epsilon,y + \epsilon[\\
]1 - \epsilon, 1]
$$
for some $\epsilon > 0$ and some $y \in ]\epsilon, 1 - \epsilon[$ (The three cases correspond to the cases $f(x) = 0$, $f(x) \in ]0, 1[$ and $f(x) = 1$, respectively.) Then if $B$ is any open subset of $]0, 1[$, write $B$ as the union of sets $]x - \delta, x + \delta[$ where $x$ in $B$ and  where $\delta$ is sufficiently small for one of the above three cases to hold and for $]x - \delta, x + \delta[$ to be contained in $B$. Hence write $f(B)$ as a union of open subsets of $[0, 1]$. (This shows that $f$ is an open mapping.) Taking $B = f^{-1}(A)$ gives that $A = f(B)$ is open if $f^{-1}(A)$ is open.